# How to start JavaDB by Java Program?

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, java-8, javadb

I am using JDK 8, in windows 10. I am developing a desktop based standalone JavaFX GUI application by using JavaDB and Hibernate. I can start the database from Net-beans and it is working fine. But to use the database either i need Net-beans or command line. But when it will be in production then what will happen?

So, i want to know is there any way to start the database from java source code?
I think it is possible because if Net-beans can do it why we will not.

Comment: @rkosegi ok let me see..

Answer (score 1):

Typically in production DB servers are kept always in running mode.

From the application you just need to connect/disconnect with the db server.

So, I think you must not code to start/stop the db server in production. If you do this it will be a bad design.

Comment: i think so, but it is a standalone application and the data r not confidential.